# EF6 Override model builder for individual table?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am a bit a ways into my project and have run into a stumbling block with the pluralization:
I need it off!

It is, by default, renaming my "...history" table to "...histories".  From the many many articles, I got the following piece of override:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
  }
```

This is great, if I wanted to change the entire dbcontext over to remove pluralization, which the other 15 tables have come to depend on.  I added the override, the one table I want to work does, and many others start to fail.

At this point, is there a way to override the model builder for a particular table, some how?  If not, how do I go about unraveling this problem...

Option 3) (ugly):  just let EF name my tables?  Deal with "Histories" and "Lists"

Using:  MVC5, EF6.0, VS 2015 community, sql 2008 server through connectionstring, code-first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the default using ToTable():

```
modelBuilder.Entity<History>().ToTable("History");
```

You can do it by annotation as well:

```
[Table("History")]
public class History{}
```

Comment: Adding [Table("NonPluralName-MYNAMEDONTCHANGE")] worked like a charm on a new table it was trying to pluralize.

Thank you!  I will have to see if I can retroactively fit the other models with this....

Comment: Yay, going back into the model and adding the tag to the tables I want, then running an add-migration immediately generated a rename.  Woop Woop!